# How to add width and height of fragment programatically?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to add  a fragment to MainActivity but when I am adding a fragmnet to it, it is covering the full width and height of main activity. So how to set the width and height of fragment to wrap content programatically, not using XML.

Here is the code of what I have do so far:

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rekl"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ankit.fragment2.MainActivity">


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Fragment3 f=new Fragment3();

FragmentManager m=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction t=m.beginTransaction();
    t.add(R.id.rekl,f,"Frag");
            t.commit();

            }
            }
```

Comment: set the width and height on R.id.rekl.

Comment: Show your Activity xml